# CSS bleed-thru on tags

Tags: bug, status-completed, design

I'm seeing an issue with CSS on Firefox (22, Windows) where the little triangles in the new tag icons are bleeding through popups.

Here's a screenie:

[image: screen shot]

I have not checked it in other browsers.

Comment: By the way, this is still happening.

Comment: I saw something similar on Pro Webmasters and filed this on meta StackExchange: [CSS z-index causes part of tags to show through the “You have X votes left today” and other notifications on webmasters and web applications](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/243133/css-z-index-causes-part-of-tags-to-show-through-the-you-have-x-votes-left-today)

Comment: I'm deleting this due to lack of activity, not on your part put the powers that be. You can create a new bug if this issue is still present.

Comment: @phwd The post linked by Stephen is as of November 6th, 2014 and links to this question.

Comment: Since the site has been redesigned this question is moot.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

[Geoff Dalgas♦](https://meta.stackexchange.com/users/2/geoff-dalgas) says [this issue has been fixed](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/243133/css-z-index-causes-part-of-tags-to-show-through-notifications-on-webmasters-web/250700#250700):

> You have caught my attention on this one. A fix has been pushed and will build out soon. I also want you to know that our design team has been hard at work at converting all of our .less files to a consistent and uniform layout which will solve most of these issues in the future. Thanks for the report and we'll keep you posted on the status of the conversion.